# Why gzip is not working with chained proxy?

Tags: nginx, proxy

Here is my first proxy that proxies second proxy:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name example.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/example.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/example.pem;

  location / {
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=10s;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://second-example;
  }
}
```

and here is my second proxy (http://second-example) that proxies my app index.html

```
    server {
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        listen 80;

        gzip on;
        gzip_types text/css application/javascript application/json image/svg+xml;
        gzip_comp_level 9;
        etag on;

        location / {
          alias  /var/www/html/;
          index index.html;
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
```

When i open a website by the second proxy directly, all files gets compressed by gzip.
But when i open a website by the first proxy, files dont get compressed

I have tried to open my website by first proxy, but it doesn't compress